# Java generics - having trouble with a tricky situation

Tags: java, generics

I've beat my head against the wall on this one for several hours now, and I've distilled it down to a tiny bit of code. Can you see where the error is?

```
public class Experiment {
   class BaseMessage<Messageable> {
      Messageable once;

      BaseMessage(Messageable x) {
         once = x;
      }
   }

   class BaseEntity {
      boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<BaseEntity> theMessage) {
         return false;
      }

   }

   class StateMachine<Thing> {
      public boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<Thing> msg) {
         return true;
      }

   }

   class VehicleEntity extends BaseEntity {
      public StateMachine<VehicleEntity> state;

      @Override
      boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<VehicleEntity> theMessage) {
         return state.handleMessage(theMessage);
      }
   }
}
```

I get a compiler error on this line:

```
boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<VehicleEntity> theMessage) {
```

The error is: `"The method handleMessage(Experiment.BaseMessage<Experiment.VehicleEntity>) of type Experiment.VehicleEntity must override or implement a super type method"`

Note that this is a sample subset of my real code to reduce it to its minimum so the code doesn't do anything sensible. Wow, if you could figure this out I would be super grateful!

Comment: In `VehicleEntity` you have `handleMessage(BaseMessage<VehicleEntity> theMessage)` not `handleMessage(BaseMessage<BaseEntity> theMessage)` and the compiler wants the latter.

Comment: Naming your generic parameters something that could be read as a type could become confusing later on (`Messageable` in `BaseMessage`, `Thing` in `StateMachine`).

Comment: @Jeffrey, I know what you mean... I find one letter names equally confusing for me when I am writing and reading the code. Better suggestion?

Comment: @pitosalas Use a [metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) that you wouldn't create a type for (I suppose `Thing` might count). However, since 90% of programmers use one letter names for generic parameters (at least in Java), it might be a good idea to start getting used to them.

Comment: @Misearable: I tried that along the way, and that gives me this error: "The method handleMessage(Experiment.BaseMessage<Experiment.VehicleEntity>) in the type Experiment.StateMachine<Experiment.VehicleEntity> is not applicable for the arguments (Experiment.BaseMessage<Experiment.BaseEntity>)"

Comment: I suggest you write the client code and decide how you want to use the API and then work backwards to generic declaration that can meet those constraints

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Miserable Variable, in `VehicleEntity` you have `handleMessage(BaseMessage<VehicleEntity> theMessage)` not `handleMessage(BaseMessage<BaseEntity> theMessage)` and the compiler expects the latter in your original code.

The main alternative is for BaseEntity to take a "self" type argument as follows:

```
class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntity<T>> {
  boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<T> message) {
    ...
  }
}
class VehicleEntity extends BaseEntity<VehicleEntity> {
  boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<VehicleEntity> message) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Miserable is correct about the cause for the original error, but I don't think he/she made the fix entirely clear.  This is a _different_ suggestion from Miserable's.  (Miserable's solution works _if_ you could change all of the callers, but the error message you reported suggests you didn't or couldn't.)  Go ahead and try this approach.

Comment: `class BaseEntity<T>` is sufficient for the OP's purposes

Comment: The additional constraint on `T` makes it more difficult to accidentally mess up, and makes it somewhat clearer that this is supposed to be the same class that's being implemented.  After all, what's the point of generics if not letting you constrain acceptable types?

Answer (score 1):

`BaseMessage<VehicleEntity>` is not a subtype of `BaseMessage<BaseEntity>`. Try this

```
abstract class BaseEntity {
    abstract <B extends BaseEntity> boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<B> theMessage) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work either, I get: "The method handleMessage(Experiment.BaseMessage<Experiment.VehicleEntity>) of type Experiment.VehicleEntity must override or implement a super type method"... stumped

Answer (score 0):

You would like for `VehicleEntity` to have a `handleMessage` method that will accept only a `BaseMessage<VehicleEntity>`.

I believe this is only possible in Java, at least it cannot be checked statically. But you may want to look at [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to see if you can make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding generics to the class itself

```
   class BaseEntity<T> {
      boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<T> theMessage) {
         return false;
      }

   }
```

And

```
   class VehicleEntity extends BaseEntity<VehicleEntity> {
      public StateMachine<VehicleEntity> state;

      @Override
      boolean handleMessage(BaseMessage<VehicleEntity> theMessage) {
         return state.handleMessage(theMessage);
      }
   }
```